# Adding Styling to svelte-routing Link tag in svelte js

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I wanted to add Styling to the `<Link>` tag in svelte routing but I couldn't.
I have tried to add a class in which there is some styling but it didn't work.

```
<Link to='/' class='link'></Link>
```

the class contains:

```
.link {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `<Link></Link>` component represents a html `<a></a>` tag.

You can use the `global` svelte-css option:

```
<style>
    .link > :global(a) {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    :global(a) {
        ...
    }
</style>
```

See also global-REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/be432b377c7549e8b60ed10452065f52?version=3.8.1

Another way is to modify the `Link.svelte` component in the svelte-routing package itself. This can be done inside your node_modules folder or you can fork the repository (https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing) and do the changes.

Comment: Thanks! Although it's a bit late to say it.

Comment: When trying your suggestion, I can't seem to get it work. Setting any styling inside the `:global(a){}` doesn't get applied and vs code says that it is unused. What am I missing here?

Comment: @DannyBoy if you add the :global(a) to the parent's style it should work. 
For example:  

`.link-wrapper > :global(a) {text-decoration: none;}`
  
`<div class="link-wrapper">
  <Link to='/' class='link'></Link>
</div>`

Answer (score 5):

You can use this option:

```
import { link } from 'svelte-routing';
...
<a href='/' class='link' use:link></a>
```

this gives you the same behavior and lets you add styles

source: https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing#link-1

Comment: Unfortunately it does not give the same behavior. It behaves like an `<a>` tag by refreshing the page when changing the URL.

Comment: be sure that you hare using `link` and not `Link`

Comment: this solution is correct. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

There are some open pull requests about the issue you mentioned:

- https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing/pull/128
- https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing/pull/123
- https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing/pull/116

Maybe try following up on those issues